# Java 7 platform independent Base64?

Tags: java, android, base64, cross-platform, java-7

I am trying to make an app that will work on multiple platforms including android. The problem I'm having is that my `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` works on the app running on the computer:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] data = decoder.decodeBuffer(is);
```

It's not working on an android device:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18172): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lsun/misc/BASE64Decoder;
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):    at com.company.app.backend.SomeClass$1.run(SomeClass.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "sun.misc.BASE64Decoder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):    ... 2 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):        ... 3 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18172):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Unfortunately I can not use Java 8's `java.util.Base64` because I can't use Java 8. Also I can not use `android.util.Base64` since it will not work outside of android.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You might use the [iharder base64 library](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use third party libraries, you can use [commons-codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

If not, you can find plenty of pure Java implementations online. Even the Wikipedia article has a [code sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Sample_Implementation_in_Java). Just add it to your own utility class.

Comment: The codec's Base64 doesn't accept streams, only a byte array. Is there one that can read from streams?